# Covering up tile gaps

Tags: walls

There are some holes in between these walls:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What are some proper (and inexpensive) ways to cover them up such that:

- they can't be seen
- crawlies are not able to get in

Comment: [pre sealed premixed grout](https://www.google.com/search?q=pre+sealed+premixed+grout&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grout - you are going to have to trial and error the color since there are about 30 shades of white.   You need to mix the grout - super super small batch, let it dry, make sure color is close enough, then fill the gaps.   You will need to read instructions on how to do this but that is a different question.   Do not just fill the gaps with whatever you find as different coloring will look really really bad.   You can get away with some variance but can't be way off.

Comment: Other options other than grout if I can't get hold of it in DIY shops?

Comment: You could use caulk but it isn't worth your time doing it in this instance.   You can order grout from 100s of websites... you need a pretty small bag and like I said color (maybe texture) are the important factors.